# Using SendGrid's Event 'web hook' API in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, sendgrid

SendGrid do not have any ASP.NET specific documentation for their 'web hook' event notifications.

I need to pass email opens back to an ASP.NET application.

How can I do this / are there any downloadable examples online?

thx

Answer (score 1):

i am on the same page as well. we have enterprise account with sendgrid with one to one support. let me know if we can help each other. i can bug sendgrid support guy anytime. you can contact me logic(dot)programer(at)gmail(dot)com

Comment: if  any one need help over sendgrid webhook ? contact

Comment: Here is some prime advice. Although I got this working - don't bother. SendGrid, specially their free plan - is full of bugs. Mandrill offer double the emails free, and web hook is so easy to use and available on all account types.